# Deriving an equation of motion for two connected masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I've been doing some physics self-study and have come across a question that I can't seem to solve using a free-body approach. I was hoping to get some advice on a technique to use or to see if there's a flaw in my thinking. The question is as follows:

> A smaller (green) mass is being lifted from a pit by a larger (blue) mass that is sliding down an inclined plane. The smaller mass is guided by an aerial cable which it is connected to via a **vertical bar** with a **constant tension of 100N**. Friction is negligible. The system starts at rest. **Derive an equation of motion for the smaller mass**.
>
> [image: Problem]

I started by drawing a free-body diagram for the smaller mass. I aligned the x axis with the black rope being pulled by the larger mass.

[image: Free Body Diagram]

Taking the sum of forces in x:

$$\sum F_x=F_{Rope}+T \sin(\alpha)-F_{Weight} \sin(\alpha)$$

The sum of forces in y will be zero since motion is constrained:
$$\begin{align}\sum F_y=0&=T\cos(\alpha)-F_{Weight}\cos(\alpha)\\
0&=100\cos(\alpha)-20\times9.81\cos(\alpha)\\
0&=100\cos(\alpha)-196\cos(\alpha)\\
0&=-96\end{align}$$

That's where my problem is. I can't get the forces in the y axis to add up so I'm stuck. I can't help but feel that I've overlooked something obvious or am going about this the wrong way. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think a close vote is inappropriate, as the question is actually conceptual.

Comment: Could have $\cos \alpha=0$ i.e. .$\alpha=90^o$.